# Counters that flip signs in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, counter, performance

Ok so im trying to make a program and i need to have the counter start at -3 and go down by 2, but every other number has to be a positive: for example:

-3, 5, -7, 9, -11, 13, -15, 17, -19,...

any input?

I made a successful program but i feel like this is not very efficient.

```
    while ("expression")
    {
        if (j % 4 == -1) //checks if number should be negative
            j = Math.abs(j);

        if (j > 0) //makes counter a negative
            j = -j;

        j -= 2; //goes down by 2
    }
```

Comment: What's so inefficient about it?  You're running in O(n) time with just a couple of arithmetic operations; this is not the sort of thing you really need to worry about optimizing

Comment: Unless you've already generated the list of numbers, you're going to have to do an O(n) operation to generate them, so I concur with torquestomp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop and a signSwitcher variable:

```
int signSwitcher = 1;
for (int x = -3; expression; x -= 2, signSwitcher *= -1) {
    int counter = x * signSwitcher;
}
```

Comment: the problem is i dont know when the loop ends. so i cant use a for loop

Comment: Your middle term is the expression. for(initializer; boolean expression; update); You can use the same expression as your while loop. for(int i=0; true; i+=2) is identical to int i=0; while(true) { i+=2; }

Comment: Minor quibble - the variable name "shifter" made me look for >> or << in your code.  IMO, it should probably be called "sign".  May be an English/Swedish thing.  :-)

Comment: Analising what @BobSV, this is the best answer, just change the name shifter to signer lol

Answer (score 7):

Geez, you guys are all thinking wayyyy too hard.  What's wrong with the obvious and readable

```
if (counter > 0)
   counter = -1*(counter+2);
else
   counter = -1*(counter-2);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like the @Keppil solution but it's a bit too obtuse for me to give it a +1.

Comment: In my opinion I actually don't find this particularly readable. To me, the sequence is just `-3, -5, -7, -9, ...` but with every other made positive. It depends how you read the sequence, but I would argue that describing it as "negate it, add two, negate it, subtract two" is a bit weirder to think about (maybe because it's more abstract?). I would wager that mathematicians would find it less readable but maybe programmers think it's elegant...

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is actually adding 2 to each entry, but then flipping the signs.

```
int current = 1;
float sign = 1.0f;
while(current < 100) {
    current += 2;
    sign = Math.signum(sign)*-1.0f;
    System.out.println(sign*current);
}
```

This just multiplies the sign of the last entry by -1.0 (which will make the sign flip).

Comment: It's OK. Sometimes this happens, when in a rush )

Comment: Instead of `signum` take a look at `copySign`; more readable IMO.

Comment: Fixed now, but required lots of changes.  Now I'm not so happy with it any more.

Comment: You can make the following changes: `int sign = 1;` and `sign *= -1;` IMHO much easier to read, no need for dealing with floats and no need for extra method calling, thus more efficient )

Answer (score 1):

Using modulus too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 3; i < 20; i += 2) {
        int sign = ((i + 1) % 4 == 0 ? 1 : -1);
        System.out.println(i * sign);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int increment = 2;
while ("expression")
{
    j += increment * (Math.abs(j)) + increment;
    increment *= -1;
}
```

What about this?

very easy